# Sum counts given in one data.frame up to dates given in another data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to update an `audit` data frame with comparisons within another data frame:

**`test`**: data frame of number of **patients for a certain date**:

```
test <- data.frame(
        date=as.Date(c("2012-12-12","2012-12-29","2013-01-15")),
        patients=c(4,7,3)
)
        date patients
1 2012-12-12        4
2 2012-12-29        7
3 2013-01-15        3
```

**`audit`**: data frame of **audit dates**:

```
audit <- data.frame(date=as.Date(c("2012-12-31","2013-01-31")),
         count=c(NA))
        date count
1 2012-12-31    NA
2 2013-01-31    NA
```

Q: **`audit$count`** should be the **total number of patients** in **`test`** UP TO **`audit$date`**?

**THIS DOESN'T work:**

```
audit$count <- sum(test[test$date < audit$date,]$patients)
```

**How best to do it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `sapply` with the values of `audit$date`:

```
audit$count <- sapply(audit$date, function(x) sum(test$patients[test$date < x]))

        date count
1 2012-12-31    11
2 2013-01-31    14
```

Comment: +1! beats me with the exact  answer! (Congrats for 10k even if a little bit late)

Comment: @agstudy Thanks. I suppose, none of the R users on SO can keep up with your speed. ;-)